# No match for read preference of secondaryPreferred

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to a mongo-db cluster from a spring-boot application using the following connection string,

```
mongodb://{host}:27017/db?ssl=true&tlsAllowInvalidHostnames=true&retryWrites=false&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred
```

However at the start-up I am receiving the following error,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No match for read preference of secondaryPreferred?ssl=true
```

Can you please help me correct my configuration.

Kind Regards,